# Using gravity and the Higgs Field as an inertial damper

Tags: science-based, gravity

Einstein allegedly proposed a thought experiment to back up his theories of relativity, about forces due to acceleration and forces due to gravity (even though the idea had been around since Newton) being indistinguishable.

As well, a common McGuffin in space science fiction is some form of inertial dampening to reduce the destructive forces of rapid and drastic changes in velocity.

We are now fairly confident that inertia, and the counter-forces of acceleration, are due to the interaction of the Higgs Boson and Higgs Field. So, if inertial forces are the same as gravitational forces, then there has to be a connection between gravity and the Higgs Field. Otherwise, there would obviously have to be some factor that differentiates them.

My story is based on the following premise: that gravity is nothing more than the concept that the Higgs Field diminishes in 'density' as 'mass' increases. The 'gravitational force' is caused by the interaction of the Higgs Boson and this decreasing density of the Higgs Field. The Higgs Boson is 'pushed' towards the center of mass (the lowest density of the Higgs Field) by this interaction, since the force caused by the Higgs Field-Higgs Boson interaction would be lower on the side of the particle closest to the center of mass. It is sort of like the concept of 'centripetal force' and 'centrifugal force' only in reverse - we were looking at it from the wrong perspective. Gravity is not a 'pull', it is a 'push'. The 'gravity well' is not something that is 'increasing' as one goes down it, but something that is 'decreasing'.

This, incidentally, explains 'free fall' - the force of inertia caused by the acceleration of the particle due to 'gravity' exactly equals the reduction in this force due to the decreasing density of the Higgs Field, and thus no resulting force - everything is in balance.

In the context of this being a description of the physics of this world, is it internally consistent that an inertial dampening device could be a mechanism that decreases or increases the density of the Higgs Field to counter the effects of acceleration?

I am looking for answers that either offer support for this premise of inertial dampening or decisively refute it. is it a potentially feasible mechanism or not for Inertial Dampening?

**Addendum**

I should clarify that this question is about a variation on quantun physics. Relativity and Einstein have absolutely nothing to do with it, and any reference to Relativity is irrelevant and useless to the question. This is about quantum inertia. Any reference to the Higgs Boson and Higgs Fiels being responsuble for a small portion of mass is irrelevant. This question is about that portion of quantum mass that is related to inertia.

Any discussion of warping of spacetime, or any discussion about spacetime in any manner, is irreleant because the assumption of the question denies the importance of any such concept of spacetime as simply 'not needed'. It is about the Stndard Model, and variationa on the Standard Model, and field theory, only. It is about warping, compressing, distorting Quatum Fields, not this nebulous undefined poorly conceptualized concept of spacetime. Unless one is prepared to support the contention with evidentiary proof (not hypothetical proof) that somehow when a magnetic field is distorted by other magnets, the only way to account for it is that spacetime is being warped.

Although the author of [the following link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2312.07557v1.pdf) tries very hard to use Relativity and Einstein to explain it, the essence of the article is as follows, and is the focus of my question:

" **A century later, we have a much more nuanced interpretation of mass, certainly with the establishment of the standard model [6, 7, 8] and the subsequent discovery of the Higgs boson [9, 10, 11]. We now understand that inertial mass is better described as an emergent quality rather than an intrinsic property of matter, given that several fundamental particles, such as electrons, positrons and quarks, owe their inertia to a coupling with the Higgs field, while other composite particles, such as neutrons and protons, acquire inertia via the dynamical back reaction of accelerated quarks, which radiate gluons to conserve momentum (see ref. [12] for a recent review). In this context, mi ought to be viewed as a ‘place holder’ for something else, a notion we shall utilize liberally throughout this paper.** "

Unfortunately, even after presenting this, the author goes on to ignore quantum physics and dwells only on concepts from Relativity to explain the 'something else'. The intent of the question is to support the notion that inertia is an emergent quality of quantum physics, and thus so too could gravity.

This question is to be considered only from quantum physics, as an extension of the above quote. It posits that the solution to 'inertial dampening' is to be found in the Standard Model, not Relativity, and that blind adherance to Relativity is preventing physics, and especially science fiction, from advancing - Einsteinians are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Mass is the measure of inertia. The Higgs field is responsible only for a small part, about 1%, of the mass of bodies, such as I, you, Earth, the Moon, or the Sun. The lion's share, about 99%, of the mass of bodies is the binding energy of the quarks which make up the protons and neutrons in the nuclei of atoms. That is, if the Higgs field were to be completely abolished, my mass would only decrease by a few hundred grams. (The Higgs field and its boson are important because without them electrons would be massless, just like photons. But protons and neutrons would retain 99% of their mass.)

Comment: It's not the mass I am concerned about.. The mass is irrelevant. it is inertia - the entire 'things in motion...' bit.  The resistance to the change in motion. Mass alone can not account for that.

Comment: Mass **is** inertia. This is what mass is. $a = F / m$ and all that.

Comment: Mass  is NOT inertia, no matter what the 'equation' implies. Inertia is unrelated to mass, except through intermediary processes.  it might be proportional to mass, but it is secondary to mass. This false concept is what has kept any discussion of inertial dampening as simply a McGuffin instead of having sume substance in physics.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond How come inertia is unrelated to mass? I'm not sure the angle you're coming from, but at first glance it seems quite strange.

Comment: I'm afraid we won't be able to help you with your issue. Your question has a rather specific view on physics, and I'm not sure this place is the proper one for it.

Comment: Also, I dunno, man. I personally would be avoidant of using Melia's work for.. well, anything, but that's another bag of worms that isn't good for a place of polite discussion like here. I recommend checking a bit more about the dude and his sources/other projects before digging in a paper of his that didn't even had time to cool on the reviewer's tables.

Comment: Voting to close for at least (a) there isn't a specific question in an attempt to resolve a specific problem. "What are the implications" intrinsically violates the [help/dont-ask]'s book rule. (b) We don't have an official policy for "review my idea" questions and this one is too far off the "I have a problem that needs solving" path to let it slide. (c) I'm having a lot of trouble distinguishing the difference between "help me build my world" and "help me write my story." Frankly, the idea is enormously fun and would be a wonderful premise to a story... but what's the problem?

Comment: @JBH
 What happened to the 'reality check' flag?

Comment: @Mermaker
 I said inertia is not mass. It is proportional to mass in many situations, and that might look like it is related, but it is not mass. The relation is through proportionality, not causality. The Higgs Boson was hypothesized BECAUSE mass alone could not explin inertia. Inertia may be proportional to mass, and therefore mass can be a substitute for inertia with the proper constant of proportionality in certain equations, but there is definitely something else besides 'mass' that is responsible for inertia.

Comment: [If we can't burn the "reality check" tag, can we rename it?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9790/40609) It's been gone for a long time because it was being abused something awful. I've poked at the idea of a "review my idea" style of question (see [Advice: How to ask for a review of your idea](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9956/40609)), but it's not getting a lot of traction because the question type is so far outside of SE's rules.

Comment: It's worth noting the nature of the abuse. The reality check tag (now named [tag:internal-consistency]) was never intended to be a request to review an idea. Its stated purpose was always to ask for help reviewing the internal consistency of the querent's world rules (hence the name change). Unfortunately, almost no one reads tag wikis, so it was constantly used for "review my idea." The change was an effort to get people to use the original intent rather than the really-hard-to-justify-under-SE's-rules abstraction.

Comment: @Mermaker I actually discounted his ideas in my discussion of the quote, but what he said about having a nuanced interpretation of inertia was valid. That part of his discussion has merit.

Comment: @
JBH
 So if I reworked the question to first presenting a description of the physics of the story world,  then asking if the idea of using the premise of the science for an inertial dampening device is internally consistent? But that removes any connection to real world science,

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Your exact wording: 'Inertia is unrelated to mass, except through intermediary processes.". That is false. I strongly suggest you review the physics around the Higgs Boson, why it was researched, and what it should solve in the model. You have several misconceptions that can't be solved on comments.

Comment: @Mermaker
 You have agreed that this topic is well beyond you and your further input is useless. Let's leave it at that.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond What I have agreed to is that I unwilling to waste more time trying to help you with this topic. That's a different thing.

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot here. In [Relativity](https://www.f.waseda.jp/sidoli/Einstein_Relativity.pdf), the OG paper, Einstein proposes two primary tests under Appendix 3. These being the motion of mercury´s perihelion and the deflection of light around massive objects. Both of which have been confirmed rather quickly follow the papers publication.

It is important to understand however that Relativity is a classical theory, while the Higgs field is part of the Standard Model, which is itself a quantum theory. These two are fundamentally at odds because they describe the universe in different ways.

The Higgs Boson you mentioned, or more broadly the Higgs Field, is part of a Quantum Field. It is often said that the Higgs Boson gives particles their mass, but its not that easy. In fact, virtually all mass of any given particle comes from the binding energies between subatomic particles. The reason there was so much hype around the Higgs Boson is because it was a concrete prediction of the Standard Model. Without the Higgs, the Standard Model does not work. So its discovery was much more a confirmation of the standard model than anything else.

It is also important to understand what a Quantum Field does, obviously this is kinda difficult but [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmG2ah5Df4g&t=1s&ab_channel=ScienceClicEnglish) is an excellent video on the matter. The TL;DR is that in Quantum Field theory some Fields act as force carries, for instance the Electromagnetic Field has the Photon as its force carrier which can influence other fields. The important think to take away is that Quantum Field Theory is quantized, as the name implies. Something Relativity is not.

You also seem to be under the misconception that in Relativity Gravity is a force. Gravity is the result of two factors, space curvature and time. General Relativity stipulates that all objects follow straight lines through spacetime. But if the underlying spacetime is itself curved, straight lines can appear to be deflected. A classic example are two straight lines on a sphere, great circles, which will intersect at two points. These straight lines converging is analogous to gravity. You wouldnt say there is a force between the two lines pulling them together, its a feature of the underlying geometry.

[image]

This is why people say gravity is not a force, nothing is pulling on you. Rather you simply follow a straight line in a curve space, which was curved by the energy of nearby objects.

> My story is based on the following premise: that gravity is nothing
> more than the concept that the Higgs Field diminishes in 'density' as
> 'mass' increases. The 'gravitational force' is caused by the
> interaction of the Higgs Boson and this decreasing density of the
> Higgs Field. The Higgs Boson is 'pushed' towards the center of mass
> (the lowest density of the Higgs Field) by tis interaction, since the
> force caused by the Higgs Field-Higgs Boson interaction would be lower
> on the side of the particle closest to the center of mass. It is sort
> of like the concept of 'centripetal force' and 'centrifugal force'
> only in reverse - we were looking at it from the wrong perspective.
> Gravity is not a 'pull', it is a 'push'. The 'gravity well' is not
> something that is 'increasing' as one goes down it, but something that
> is 'decreasing'.
>
> This, incidentally, explains 'free fall' - the force of inertia caused
> by the acceleration of the particle due to 'gravity' exactly equals
> the reduction in this force due to the decreasing density of the Higgs
> Field, and thus no resulting force - everything is in balance. This,
> in essence, is the basis for my inertial dampening device - decrease
> the density of the Higgs Field to counter the effects of acceleration.

On all of this, there is really not much to say, its pseudo science. Idk what you image a "Decisive refute" to look like here, the way you describe these things is just not how it works.

Like we can ask some questions, like for instance why the Higgs Field diminishes as mass increases ? What mechanism does that ?

Gravity being caused by the Higgs is also kinda iffy. The Higgs has Energy so it does produce a gravitational field, but like literally every particle does that. Even a massless photon has energy. Moreover, the Higgs mechanism (like many fundamental interactions) is short ranged. And it does not really get stronger the closer an interaction occurs. Whereas gravity positively does get a lot stronger the closer two sources are. Inverse square law and all.

Lastly, i would like to say that i think you misunderstand what a Theory in Physics is meant to do. You cant prove anything in physics and no model aspires to do so. A models value is judged by how well it can make predictions. Newtonian Dynamics are no more wrong due to Relativity. Rather, Newtonian Dynamics have a smaller application range, where as Relativity works for more situations. But nobody is gonna bust out the Schwarzschild Metric when constructing a House. Both of these theories have their own place and usage.

Comment: Moderator note: I've deleted some comments from a discussion that wasn't going anywhere productive.

Comment: This entire answer goes nowhere It is completely irrelevant to the question.